# Refresh page after click on button

Tags: button, upload, page-refresh

I have a upload button but after i upload something i does not refresh the page. i thougt this would work but is doesnt:

```js
function refreshPage(){
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<span class="ff-b white ttu f21">UPLOAD<input type="button" onClick="refreshPage()"/>Close</span>
```

Do some body of you know how to fix this ?
Kind regards.

Comment: Seems to work for me. (After I edit the html code, of course)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick response. but i still doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: use this for uploading ur file